# Is necessary rebuild container to change ports or stop/start is enough?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a composer file with four services. I need to OPEN one of them to outside by settings ports.

After changing .yml file, do I need to 'rebuild the container' (docker-compose down/up) or do I just need to stop/start? (docker-compose stop/start)?

Specifically, what I neet to do accesible to outside is a Posgree Server. This is my actual postgres service definition in .yml:

```
mydb:
    image: postgres:9.4
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPassword
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I think I just need to change it to:

```
  mydb:
    image: postgres:9.4
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myPassword
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

I'm worried of loosing data on 'db-data' volume, or connection to the other services, if I use down/up.

Also, there are 3 other services specified in the .yml file. If it is necessary to REBUILD (without loosing data in db-data, of course), I don't want to touch these other containers. In this case, which would be the steps?:

- First, rebuild 'mydb' container with 'docker run' (*Could you provide me the right command, please?*)
- Modify the .yml as stated before, just adding the ports
- Perform a simple docker-compose stop/start

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Re: worried of losing data... if you're worried about losing it, you should have a backup of that data. Specifically the `db-data` directory needs to be backed up. Rebuilding shouldn't delete it by the way, but it could absolutely be corrupted if there's a bug or if you restart the container while it's half way through a write with no transaction. I've had to restore docker databases from backups plenty of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only changing settings like `ports:`, it is enough to re-run `docker-compose up -d` again.  Compose will figure out which things are different from the existing containers, and destroy and recreate only those specific containers.

If you're changing a Dockerfile or your application code you may specifically need to `docker-compose build` your application or use `docker-compose up -d --build`.  But you don't specifically need to rebuild the images if you're only changing runtime settings like `ports:`.

`docker-compose down` tears down your entire container stack.  You don't need it for routine rebuilds or container updates.  You may want to intentionally shut down the container system (and free up host ports, memory, and other resources) and it's useful then.

`docker-compose stop` leaves the containers in an unusual state of existing but without a running process.  You almost never need this.  `docker-compose start` restarts containers in this unusual state, and you also almost never need it.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question to be sure... I'm using a volume for the postgreee data, as you can see it. If I just call 'docker-compose up' (while they are running), will the data in the volume be kept?

Comment: when you says 'it figures out which things are different', what types of changes you mean? In some containers, during use, some things can have changed (like config files on the applications inside, new Python libraries added by executing a shell inside with 'docker exec -it'). Will this operations make the container elegible for rebuilding?

Comment: Compose won't notice those kinds of changes, and if it decides to reconstruct the container, it will actively discard any changes you've made with `docker cp` or `docker exec`.  Avoid these commands in routine use.

Comment: @Kaikus have a look at `docker-compose help` to see all the options. About the only thing that's missing is `docker-compose up` is frequently used with the `-d` option and sometimes the `--build` option (`-d` for run as a daemon, `--build` to rebuild which is sometimes necessary). Note building is faster the second time around, a whole bunch of stuff is cached. The project I'm working on now took half an hour to build the first time, but only takes a couple seconds now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rebuild it.

For that reason the best practice is to map all the mount points and resources externally, so you can recreate the container (with changed parameters) without any loss of data.

In your scenario I see that you put all the data in an external docker volume, so I think you could recreate it with changed ports in a safe way.

Comment: I'm using a volume, as you can see. If rebuild, the data in volume is not respected?

Comment: You rebuil the container, instead the volumes are kept.

Comment: Wich would be the command to rebuild only this container, then, please?

Comment: `docker-compose build -f  <your-docker-compose-file.yaml>`

Comment: This is wrong, it doesn't need to be rebuilt.